# Codeigniter form submission adds action url with website url

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am Trying to Submit a form in Codeigniter in form action my url is "Registration/register" when I submit it, it is adding action with existing url. My english is too bad please see attach image for detail.

Example: My Website Url is example.com/d2t/index.php/Registration
I am adding in form action like action = "Registration/register".

then it adds my form url with my website url: example.com/d2t/index.php/Registration/Registration/register

Comment: change action to `/Registration/register` instead of `Registration/register`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use site_url() method

```
action="<?php echo site_url("Registration/register") ?>"
```

or you can use the form helper :

```
echo form_open('Registration/register');
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form%20helper